# Iterate an array till provided length along with the find the count elements it covered ignoring the same element if it comes more than once

Tags: java, arrays

I have a method called `m1(int input1,int input2,int[] input3)`, which has three-parameter.Whatever value will define in `input1` the same no of element should contain in `input3[]` i.e. the length of `input3` will same as value of `input1`. And whatever value will define in `input2`, the iteration will be done in int `input3` till that length. And it has to give the count how many elements it has iterated but if the same number repeats then count value will not increase. For first time count will increase but once the same no repeats then count remains constant and when it will get different elements then count will increase but iteration will be done till the length mention in `input2`.

EXAMPLE:

```
int input1 =5;
int input2= 3;
int[] input3 ={1,2,1,3,4};
```

Expected:
so here input1 is 5 so the length of input3 is also 5.
And here input2 value is 3, so while iterating input3 it has to iterate till 2nd index i.e. till length is 3. So here the the iteration will be done till {1,2,1} and count has to come 2 as 1 is repeated 2 times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We don't need the first argument we can use input3.length to get that attribute. I have given two types of solution to this problem,

one is to use Set and other using stream. Set is a Data Structure which keeps items unique meaning, even if you add an item twice it will keep only one of them so you can get the distinct element counts out of it.

Second one is to use Java stream API where you can just use Limit and distinct operations to get the unique count.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

class Solution {
    public static int findUniqueCountUsingSet(int length, int range, int[] input) {
        Set<Integer> integers = new HashSet<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < range; i++) {
            integers.add(input[i]);
        }
        return integers.size();
    }

    public static int findUniqueCountUsingStream(int length, int range, int[] input) {
        return (int) Arrays.stream(input).limit(range).distinct().count();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(findUniqueCountUsingSet(5, 3, new int[]{1, 2, 1, 3, 4}));
        System.out.println(findUniqueCountUsingStream(5, 3, new int[]{1, 2, 1, 3, 4}));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a language that has a unique container like C++ sets, this could be one way to accomplish this. Otherwise, you could put each value in a temporary array and check with an if statement (with a small search algorithm) if it has not been added already. Then just return the size of that new array.

Answer (score 0):

One other way to do is using `stream`

```
Stream.of(input3).limit(input2).distinct().count()
```

This will give the count of distinct elements